# Calling functions/methods in default function parameters on the arguments themselves?

Tags: javascript

Is it a good practice to call functions or methods on a function's arguments to initialize parameters of that function?

For example, I want to implement quicksort and I want to define the array's leftmost and rightmost index in the function parameter itself.

```
const quicksort = function(array, l = 0, r = array.length - 1) {
    ...
}
```

Is this considered good practice? If not, why?

Comment: Sure, if you actually want those defaults, why not?

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid it. Personally, I can't understand your desire to make your parameter defaults variable in the first place. I expect variables to be declared in the scope of the function, and for default parameters to be literal constants.

That aside, you should consider your input and failure criteria. Are you OK with having a null reference exception in the header of your function if it gets called with a null `array`? If you want to handle this case gracefully, you can't reconcile reading any attributes of `array` in the header. Assumptions like this cause bugs.

I think that quicksort is a good example of where this *could* be useful, but the practice is a little sloppy when you really think about it. It's not as interesting, but I think it's cleaner if you separate the responsibility a bit:

```
const quicksort_helper = function(array, l, r) {
    // implement your quicksort here
}

const quicksort = function(array) {
    if (array === null) {
        // exit gracefully
    } else {
        quicksort_helper(array, 0, array.length);
    }
}
```